# Pop up in JS with selected dropdown fields

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

based on the code.. I want to create pop up when attach file and we need to choose dropdown field = 123 then form is was fine.. But if we forgot to select field=123 in dropdown it's will be get pop up that they need to select the fields.. How can i do that?? I'm beginner in js.. anyone can help me.. 
Thanks a lot :)

```
function PreSaveAction() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");

  if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display = 'none';
    alert("Please attach Documents");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will be better if we could see your HTML. Have a look at [mcve]

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint and just put some code in script editor..

Comment: Can you copy just the HTML generated for the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use jQuery, you could check below sample script.

```
$('select[title="DDLField"] means dropdown filed title equal DDLField.
```

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var selectedOption = $('select[title="DDLField"] option:selected').text();
            alert(selectedOption);
            if (selectedOption != "123") {
                alert("select the field");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

[image]